# Calling a contract from another contract - nothing happens

Tags: solidity, remix, metamask

I'm trying to call a contract from another contract. When I use a simple example, like below, it just works fine, no problem, the counter in contract A adds up when I trigger function in contract B:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.13;

contract A {
    uint public counter ; 
    function increment(uint add) {
       counter = counter + add;
    }
}

contract B {
    function delegateIncrement(uint add) {
        A(addressA).increment(add) ; 
    }
}
```

But when I want to incorporate a transfer function, like below, nothing happens. I don't get why. Increased gas etc already.:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.13;

contract Betaal{
    address public bedrijf = addresBedrijf;

    function UitBetalen(){
        bedrijf.transfer(this.balance);
    }

    function ()payable{
    }
}

contract Trigger{
    function TriggerBetaling() payable{
        Betaal(addressBetaal).UitBetalen;
    }   
}
```

When I the "uitbetalen" function directly in the "Betaal"contract, it works just fine, but when I want to trigger it using the "TriggerBetaling" function in the "Trigger" contract, the transaction reaches the Trigger contract just fine and then nothing happens, the uitbetalen function is not triggered. Anyone any idea?

I'm using remix and metamask, but they seem to work just fine.

Comment: You forgot parentheses after `Betaal(addressBetaal).UitBetalen`. Just add `()` to make a call.

Comment: sometimes the answer can be that simple..........thanks! wasted a beautifull 2 hours staring at my code, hahaha!

Comment: @maxtaldykin pls post as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You forgot parentheses after `Betaal(addressBetaal).UitBetalen`. Just add `()` to make a call.